# $G$-invariant complement to an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let 
$$\rho : G \to GL(V)$$
be a complex representation of $G$.

Suppose we have an internal direct sum decomposition 
$$V=W \oplus U$$
where $W$ is infinite dimensional and $U$ is finite dimensional and nonzero. Assume further that $W$ is $G$-invariant.

Does there exist a subspace $U' \subseteq V$ such that $U'$ is $G$-invariant and $V=W \oplus U'$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is such a $U'$, by Maschke's Theorem, which states that if $V$ is a representation of a finite group over a field of characteristic zero, and $W$ is a subrepresentation, then it has a complement $U'$ that is also a subrepresentation. Some introductions to representation theory might only state Maschke's Theorem for finite dimensional representations, as they will often only be concerned with the finite dimensional case, but if you look at the usual proof then you'll see that it nowhere uses the fact that $W$ is finite dimensional.

Also, there is no need to assume that $W$ has a finite dimensional vector space complement $U$.

Comment: As a service to the readers, you might at least give the statement of a sufficiently general version of Maschke's theorem.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Well, the statement is pretty much what was in the question, but you're probably right that I should make this more explicit, which I've now done.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks for the answer! I was able to find a proof of the theorem in its full generality. One question though, this version of Maschke's theorem tells us that we may always find a $G$-invariant complement, but not that this process will eventually terminate. Is the axiom of choice required anywhere to fully decompose the space into irreducibles?

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes, the axiom of choice is needed, even if $G$ is the trivial group. In that case, representations are just vector spaces, irreducible representations are just one-dimensional vector spaces, and the statement that every representation is a direct sum of irreducibles is basically the fact that every vector space has a basis, which needs the axiom of choice. Even the fact that every subspace has a complement needs the axiom of choice, so the existence of $U$ in the way you stated the problem needs it.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no, not in general.  Of course this is not true in the finite dimensional case, and making $W$ infinite dimensional does nothing to help the situation. Here's kind of a contrived example:

Let's say $G$ acts on trivially on the infinite dimensional vector space $W$.
Now let $K$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$ with a $G$-invariant subspace $U$, but such that $U$ does not have a $G$-invariant complement.

Now $K\oplus W$ is an infinite dimensional representation of $G$ with an infinite dimensional $G$ invariant subspace $U\oplus W$, but this subspace has no $G$-invariant complement.

Comment: Complex representations of finite groups are completely reducible (semisimple), unlike what you suggest. Did you read the question carefully?

Comment: This is certainly true in the finite dimensional case, though the proof I'd seen explicitly used the finiteness. Turns out it's true for arbitrary dimensions. Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem